# How do I get different formats for first and other items in nested list in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to have nested enumerated lists with the following layout:

```
1. a.
   b.
   c.
2.
3. a.
   b.
```

How do I do this in Word? I know it's possible in LaTeX, but that's unfortunately not an option in this case.

I have access to Word 2003 and Word 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Doing literally what you ask is to the best of my knowledge impossible with the numbering mechanism built in Word. And you do want keep using numbering mechanism, because otherwise you will get all sort of headaches with keeping the numbered list consistent upon insertions, deletions and cross references. Besides this, Word is fairly flexible with what you can do with nested lists.

The best you can get is this: [image]

You achieve that in two steps.

1. You have to define your format of nested (multilevel) list; in the main ribbon go to the [image: Multilevel list icon], and choose "Define new multilevel list". There you should select the second level to modify ([image: like that]) , in the textbox "Enter formatting for number:" put cursor in the leftmost position, from the list "Include level number from:" select "Level 1", and optionaly put comma "." after inserted label in textbox "Enter formatting for number:". The end result should look [image: like that] Pres OK.
2. The list is already selected, so you can use it as you would use any multilevel list.

Comment: Please check that you're not overwriting other revisions — I edited your post to properly include the images.

Comment: Thank you. You did it just a few seconds faster than me. I overwrote your edits, because I realized that my answer is not fully to the point - see the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tab key.

For example if you're at 1, if you press tab, your list will change from 1 to a but not forgetting that you must define your numbering list on your number's icon on your toolbar.

Move your mouse to the number icon. Next to the icon is a down arrow, click it if you want the a,b,c type of numbering. If not, scroll down and click "define new number format" and type the format you want – then click OK.

Comment: This does not enable me to get the 1.a. as first item

Answer (score 0):

1. Type "1. Hello" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will transform it into a list.
2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will replace the "2." by "a." and indent it.

You can then switch between different list levels by indenting and unindenting the elements. For example, after finishing your elements *a* to *c*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch from "d." to "2.".

Comment: This does not enable me to get the 1.a. as first item

Comment: There is no way to get "1.a.", and, honestly, doesn't make too much sense. You can still replace Word list by hand-made list, or use text blocks or a table; both approaches are unprofessional and will cause trouble for later changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with a way when trying to do my 8th grade science homework.
Follow the pictures:
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Result:
[image: result]